# Set Listview or stackpanel Height so it doesnt go over page edge

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

[image: Layout Wanted]

This is the layout I'm trying to get, the image 1 is a set size and has a bottom margin of 10, when any list is populated and it is too big it just goes over the page if its only got one item in the lists everything shrinks, if i manually set a height to the borders i get the result I'm after but only for my resolution, so basically i want the stackpanel to be the same height as screen it is on but not to overflow the page, and the borders to be auto height but the maximum height it can be wthout pushing the image over or shrinking if there is nothing in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to get the Screen size via code and try to calculate the maximum size for items and minus their margins in height..

and set it manually for every Item.

the problem with the auto height is when there is no items, the height is basically 0.

And try to use % if possible for a more flexible layout..

Or you could show me some of your code to better help you..